# Keyboard number pad not working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, troubleshooting

I am running Ubuntu 9, and recently I have a very strange error.

My number pad on my keyboard don't work. Its not hardware since I changed the keyboard and I still have the same problem.

Comment: does the NumLock LED light up?  does it work when numlock is on/off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be your mouse settings. Your keyboard is set to move the cursor with your number pad.

To Slove this issue

1. Go to System > Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard Accessibility
2. Select [x] Enable keyboard accessibility features
3. Go to the tab Mouse Keys and deselect [ ] Enable keyboard accessibility features.

similar to article:  http://arcanecode.com/2007/04/25/ubuntu-704-and-virtual-pc-2007-mouse-issue-workaround-sort-of/

Comment: thanks it worked :D ... only that in ubuntu 9 they are in System > Preferences > Keyboard > Mouse Keys

Comment: How can I do this in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mouse pointer moves, when you press 4 on the numeric pad?
If so your keyboard are in the incredibly annoying mouse keys state.

[shift]+[num lock] dosen't work for me on ubuntu 14.10

- Enter the system settings menu
- select "accessibility"
- Choose the last tab
  The top switch is "mouse keys" Switch it of!

Answer (score 1):

On a **Mint 18.2** encountered a similar problem
**Menu > Accessibility > Mouse** > `switch off` **Control the pointer using the keypad**
`screen guide`:
[switch on numpad linux mint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDllY.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to System>Control center > Keyboard Preferences > Accessibility tab, then Disable Accessibility features can be toggled with keyboard shortcuts

This worked for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS